When will a laravel model creation fail without an exception?
I am adding a store method to a controller that will create and save a new model to the database using the following code:
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
       'name' => 'required|string',
       'description' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $team = Book::create($validated);

    $request->session()->flash('flash_message', "Book created successfully.");

    return redirect("/site/books");
}

It was said that if the Book creation fails for any reason, there will be an exception generated which will prevent the flash() from occurring, therefor that line does not need to be wrapped in an if() statement to check if the Book was actually created (nor a try/catch block or database transaction).  Is this accurate?  Are there situation where the creation could fail without an error or exception, which would result in an inaccurate success message?  If so, how do I prevent this?

"Are there situations where the creation could fail without an error or exception [...]" - Not that I know of... You're validating your input, which ideally would prevent any bad data being passed to your create() method, but if your code still failed (database down/inaccessible, DB error due to a validation/schema mismatch, etc.), it will trigger an Exception (I don't recall the subtypes), so you should do try { Model::create(...); } catch (Exception $ex) { /* Logic to handle, error message, etc. */ }

Re: transactions, you should use one if you're creating multiple Models, i.e. a Model and Related Model that's dependent. If you first create() call is successful, but the 2nd fails, then you'd want to wrap all of that code in a DB::transaction() call (or manually create and Rollback a Transaction, etc.). For a single call to ::create(), a try/catch is generally good enough.

while the flash will not happen on an insertion failure, you may still want to do some handling of your own for that case, since currently the user would be redirected to a default "error 500" page (assuming APP_DEBUG=false) without any indication of what went wrong. One option would be to wrap the create in a try-catch and flash an error message when something goes wrong.

$team = Team::create($validated);

Given that team was actually created (as a new class), $team will be that new object.
Therefore, in the very unlikely event that no exception was thrown albeit not stored to the database (or lost there afterwards directly), you still can use the identity of $team to confirm your expectations or requirements.
E.g. you can make the message show some property of the new entry so that the message has more information and value for the user.
This is to improve the usability (more speaking messages for your users, e.g. multiple tabs with multiple recordset creations, or a group of users work together and they need to discuss / review things). This recommendation is not to highlight the actual error checks were insufficient.
To clarify this again by repeating it one more time risking it becomes dull:
We use the Laravel Eloquent Model protocol ::create() method with the expectation that it works and creates the object and stores it into the database unless running over an exceptional situation.
All exceptional situations in Laravel are taken care of automatically, so technically speaking, the try / catch is extra love you put therein but not required.

Could you describe what that unlikely event might look like?  Also, to confirm expectations, should I check to see that the fields are present and the data base entry exists?  Anything else?  Thanks!

That unlikely event might be for example a software or a hardware bug. " should I check to see that the fields are present and the data base entry exists?" That depends and what you consider your requirements. Personally I would not recommend that, because we're using the abstractions not to check them for all their side effect but just to rely on the side effects. As outlined in the example, we think positive and we may than improve the message for our user instead of continuing to loose directions and getting lost in what could be an error for some of the seconds in a future moon phase.

What kind of check would you recommend?

What you have looks sufficient to me. Therefore I would not recommend any additional checks. Albeit I have not run your code (would require more setup etc.), this is where I'm coming from: I consider Book::create(...) to work when I use it in code. The protocol is clear and exceptions are exceptions (and handled).  After having good tests with it, I'd do another check run how the UI/Interaction can be improved from the users perspective. This is certainly beyond what you ask for, just to stress that no more error handling should be necessary on that low level you ask about.

You can use try catch method to handle exceptions
public function store(Request $request) {
$validated = $request -> validate([
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'description' => 'required|string',
]);
try {
    $team = Book:: create($validated);

    $request -> session() -> flash('flash_message', "Book created successfully.");

    return redirect("/site/books");
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return back()->with('error', 'Failed to create book. Please try again. ' . $e->getMessage());
}

